# Synonym for the word helpful or caring

Tags: meaning, word-choice, single-word-requests, nouns, language-formation

I host international students and am always helping others. Whats a good word to express my desire to help others? I want a japanese tattoo with a powerful word but dont know what to use that relates to me helping them learn the English Language and Canadian Culture.

Comment: So do you want an English word or a Japanese one?

Comment: Well I'm going to get the Japanese word that means the same thing in English

Comment: Please note: The meaning of words in different languages may not always fully overlap - simply translating from English to Japanese might not lead to the desired result. IMHO it would be a better choice to ask a native Japanese speaker which term or phrase would be appropriate.

Comment: You really want to get a tattoo? Man, that's dedication!

Comment: Yeah I have Japanese students come year round so i'll be asking then and their teachers. Thanks and yeah!

Comment: As pointed out by others, this is a question about Japanese and not English. Additionally, coming up with synonyms is off-topic here because that's what thesauri are there for.

Answer (score 1):

the word is *benevolent*.

**adjective:**
1. characterized by or expressing goodwill or kindly feelings.
2. desiring to help others; charitable.
3. intended for benefits rather than profit.

**Synonyms**: good, kind, humane, generous, liberal, benign, philanthropic, altruistic.

please see: http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/benevolent

Answer (score 0):

**[Philanthropist](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/philanthropist)** should do the trick.

A person who practices *philanthropy*

> altruistic concern for human welfare and advancement, usually manifested by donations of money, property, or work to needy persons, by endowment of institutions of learning and hospitals, and by generosity to other socially useful purposes.
>   1600-10; earlier *philanthropia* < Late Latin < Greek *philanthrōpía* love for mankind.
>   <sub>Source: [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/philanthropy)</sub>

Comment: I have no idea what the Japanese equivalent would be. :)

Answer (score 0):

How about "omotenashi" or "おもてなし"?  In English, it roughly translates to "hospitality".  You can read about the meaning of "omotenashi" here: http://www.kanebo.com/beautyadvice/omotenashi/omotenashi.html
This is quite a powerful word in Japan; the idea of "omotenashi" was famously used to promote Japan's successful bid for the 2020 Olympics.